# ¿cómo pasar una variable recibida como parámetro en una función publica a una función hija en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

estoy teniendo problemas para pasar una variable recibida como parámetro en una función pública y necesito pasar este valor a una función hija, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a id?

Comment: ¿a qué función deseas pasar el `id`?, además de eso por favor edita y coloca el código como texto, te recomiendo leer [ask]